# Why is table CHARSET set to utf8mb4 and COLLATION to utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin, character-encoding, collation

I've recently noticed that, when ever I start a new WordPress project, my tables' collation automatically changes from `utf8_unicode_ci` (which I select when I create a new DB from phpMyAdmin) to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

Also, I've noticed in phpMyAdmin under “General Settings” that server connection Collation defaults to `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci`.

I'm running MySQL Server 5.7.17 and phpMyAdmin 4.6.6 on Ubuntu 17.04.

My questions are following:

1. Why is this happening?
2. If possible, how do I prevent this? Because of `utf8mb4` I've experienced problems when migrating WP sites to an older MySQL server which does not support it.
3. Is point 2. advisable? Are there any benefits in using charset `utf8mb4` over `utf8`, and collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` over `utf8_unicode_ci`?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

In the past, there was only `utf8` (aka `utf8mb3`); <strike>in the future, utf8mb4 will be the default character set.</strike> now `utf8mb4` is the default character set.

In the past, `_general_ci` was the default collation; then `_unicode_ci` (Unicode 4.0) was better, then `_unicode_520_ci` (Unicode 5.20).  In the future (MySQL 8.0), the default will be `_0900_ci_ai` (Unicode 9.0).

Meanwhile, the road is full of potholes generated by MySQL's past mistakes.  And WP designers are driving in a big tank that does not notice the potholes.

MySQL 5.6 was a big pothole that swallowed up many a WP user because of a 767 limit on indexes together with WP indexes on the overly-long `VARCHAR(255)` and the possibility of using `utf8mb4`.  You are well past it by having 5.7.17.  (Your future move to 8.0 will be less bumpy.)

That is, newly created databases/tables/columns on 5.7.7+ should not experience the 767 problem, but things migrated from older versions (5.5.3+) may have issues, especially if something causes you to change to utf8mb4.

What to do?  I'll probably run out of space trying to spell out all the options.  So provide the history of the data, the upgrade path (if any), the current settings, the `ROW_FORMAT` of the tables, the `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION` of the columns, the output of `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`

Where should you be?  For 5.7.7+, `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci` wherever practical.  That charset gives you Emoji and all of Chinese (utf8 does not).  That collation is the best available, although you might be hard pressed to notice where it matters.

Note: the first part of the collation name is the only character set that it works with.  That is `utf8_unicode_ci` does not work with `utf8mb4`.

For MySQL 8.0, there is a better collation than the  one mentioned in the title.  In general, simply use the default collation for the chosen charset (unless you have some compatibility issue of language-specific need).

Comment: Great answer, thank you Rick. My only problem was when migrating to older MySQL servers. So just for a future reference, it's a better idea to try to upgrade MySQL server, if possible, instead of converting CHARSET and COLLATION back to Unicode 4.0. Thanks again.

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ - Thanks for fluffing my ego.  Yes, move forward, not backward.

Comment: @RickJames When will the next major collation version support be released (such as `0900_ci_ai`) and where can we follow it's development please? Quoting it on Google yields zero results.

Comment: Search for "utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci".  (And I see my cheat sheet on the first page.)  Oracle does not release Release dates; I _guess_ 8.0 will be GA well into 2018, since there are _major_, unrelated, structural changes in the product.

Comment: A quick glance seems to say that latin-based collations of 520 and 900 are the same.  I don't know about Cyrillic.  (Twist my arm and I will write a program to do that analysis.)

Comment: MySQL 8.0.11 is GA as of 2018-04-19.

Comment: It is not better, I cannot use MySQL 8.0 in my configuration. So for now my customers will remain in Ubuntu 18 and Mysql 5.7. After a week struggling our company is considering another database even.