# MySQL `where` bug when using utf8mb4 emojis?

Tags: mysql, unicode

MySQL `WHERE` doesn't seem to work as expected when handling 4-byte characters like emojis. Here's how to reproduce from MySQL Workbench:

```
-- Enable utf8mb4 in MySQL workbench
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';

CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4;

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`text`) VALUES
("ABC"), (""), (""), ("");

SELECT `text` FROM `mytable`
WHERE `text` = "";
```

Expected result

```
+------+
| text |
+------+
|    |
+------+
```

Actual result

```
+------+
| text |
+------+
|    |
|    |  <-- ??
+------+
```

I've verified this behavior in both 5.6.32 and 5.7.20.

Please enlighten me what's going on.
**Thanks**

Comment: I've always thought it was happy chocolate ice cream...

Comment: A pterodactyl flew over and pooped on your head.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a MySQL bug but rather a good lesson on what COLLATE is and it's importance to set it properly. The collation is used when comparing strings.

The COLLATE clause can be used in the select statement

```
SELECT `text` FROM `mytable`
WHERE `text` COLLATE utf8mb4_bin = "";
```

or the table altered permanently

```
ALTER TABLE `mytable` 
CHANGE COLUMN `text` `text` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8mb4' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_bin' NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

It could be set when the table was created as well

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `text` TEXT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a newer collation:

```
SELECT ""="" COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci;  --> 0
SELECT ""="" COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;  --> 1
```

"unicode_ci" is based on Unicode 4.0; "unicode_520_ci" is based on version 5.20.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43692337