# Double Encoded UTF-8 String - MySql, Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, character-encoding, dropwizard

We are saving a string in MySQL DB after encoding it using Base64 using hibernate.

Following is the code that does this:

```
    @Basic
    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    @ColumnTransformer(read = "FROM_BASE64(name) ", write ="TO_BASE64(?)")
    public String getName()
```

Now, when I am saving *rotebühlstr*, this is getting saved in DB as *cm90ZWLDvGhsc3Ry*. When I print it on terminal, this is shown as *rotebÃ¼hlstr* where as it should be *rotebühlstr*

This is a dropwizard project and config.yaml for mysql connection is as follow:

```
      properties:
      charSet: UTF-8
      characterEncoding: UTF-8
      useUnicode: true
      hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
      hibernate.jdbc.batch_size: 100
      hibernate.envers.audit_table_suffix: "_aud"
      hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings: false
```

MySQL column description : `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

```
    mysql> show variables like 'character_set_%';
    +--------------------------+--------------------------------------- 
    --------------------+
    | Variable_name            | Value                                                     
    |
    +--------------------------+--------------------------------------- 
    --------------------+
    | character_set_client     | utf8mb4                                                   
    |
    | character_set_connection | utf8mb4                                                   
    |
    | character_set_database   | utf8mb4                                                   
    |
    | character_set_filesystem | binary                                                    
    |
    | character_set_results    | utf8mb4                                                   
    |
    | character_set_server     | latin1                                                    
    |
    | character_set_system     | utf8                                                      
    |
    | character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/mysql-5.7.23-macos10.13- 
    x86_64/share/charsets/ |
    +--------------------------+--------------------------------------- 
    --------------------+
    8 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Observation:

> In my colleague's local set up, this is working fine. There,
>   java/hibernate is treating input string in latin1 and not in UTF-8.
>   so, *rotebühlstr* is encoded in DB as *cm90ZWL8aGxzdHI=* and decoded
>   correctly as *rotebühlstr*.

^This was happening because of difference in character_set_server. It was set as latin1 in my local and as utf-8 in colleague's local.

What we have tried so far:

- Tried sending "Accept-Charset" as latin1. Didn't work.
- Tinkered with config.yaml file to change charset setting for mysql. Didnt work

What I can do now:

I can may be write a wrapper layer for encoding and decoding and stop using @ColumnTransformer. That way problem can be fixed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem with charsets one time and the only charset could fix the problem was utf8mb4. As I can remember The problem arises from that utf8 cannot support some characters.

Additionally, for more information, you can check https://stackoverflow.com/a/43692337/2137378 too.

Comment: We are using utf8mb4 for encoding and utf8mb4_unicode_ci as collation. It works in someone's local and doesn't work in some, so it might be something to do with the local set up of DB. I will try using utf8mb4 and utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci as suggested in the answer.

Comment: I had not change default settings of my mysql db. Then I think the time it worked may has the default settings too. good luck

Answer (score 1):

It works on your colleague, but not on your terminal, because yours is connected with latin1 charset, even though the database and field might be in utf8mb4.

You want to find your mysql config and add these options in their sections. Create the sections if they're missing.

```
[mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[mysqld]
character_set_server = utf8mb4
collation_server = utf8mb4_general_ci
```

Exit any clients, restart the server and you should be fine. Also from now on when you do a `show create database` or `show create table` you will see when it's the wrong encoding.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. It didnt work. my.cnf is as follow:  
       [mysql]
default-character-set=utf8mb4

[client]
default-character-set=utf8mb4
# Default Homebrew MySQL server config
[mysqld]
character_set_server = utf8mb4
collation_server = utf8mb4_general_ci
# Only allow connections from localhost
bind-address = 127.0.0.1

Comment: I stopped my mysql server and started again. 

show create table shows me this for my column : `name` varchar(200) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,

Thank You!

Comment: If it shows you the charset in the statement, it means it's a different charset than the one you're connected with. Otherwise the charset is hidden. There might be another configuration read somewhere that sets the charset for your client to something else.

Comment: Try opening the console with `mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4` or run the `show variables like 'character_set_%';` command to see if something is not right. The `character_set_system` value is one that you can't control in any way.

Comment: character_set_server : latin1

This is the only one where I see latin1. I will add the result of show variables like 'character_set_%'; in question description.

Comment: That would mean the setting is overridden somewhere in another config file.

Comment: Do you think this would help? https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/59126/set-value-of-character-set-client-to-utf8mb4

Comment: Yes, try that. The problem almost certainly is with the MySQL configuration.

Comment: Another point: I checked with my colleague's laptop, his character_set_server is utf-8. So, if I change my character_set_server from latin1 to utf-8, I have removed the discrepancy and but the problem of double encding in UTF-8 still persists.

Comment: The problem occurs _before generating_ `cm90ZWL8aGxzdHI=`.  Instead, `base64_encode('rotebühlstr') = 'cm90ZWLDvGhsc3Ry'`

Comment: @RickJames I am sorry, but I am unable to understand your suggestion.

Comment: @H-V - You have not shown the code that we need to discuss.  It is _earlier_ that what you have shown.